# Safari / Chrome can’t connect to internet, FaceTime / Mail still working

Tags: safari, google-chrome, internet, facetime

My M1 MacBook crashed last night (woke to find the login screen & all users logged out). The Mac asked to send an error report.

Since logging in again I can not access the internet from Safari or Chrome, images in Mail don’t load. Google Drive is reporting no internet connection etc

Chrome is reporting that I have no internet. Safari can’t connect to the server.

However, I am able to send/receive emails and make FaceTime calls.

I’ve tried restarting in Safe Mode which wasn’t successful.

This applies to all users on the machine.

I’m running 12.2.1

Comment: Is your MacBook using a wired or wireless connection? Or both? I ask because something similar has been happening to me but without the crash.

Comment: I'm just using a wireless internet connection, but have checked multiple networks and they all have the same issue. Other devices work fine on these networks

Comment: In **System Preferences** > **Network**, have you tried making the interface inactive and then active again (don't forget to **Apply**)? I have done this to my Ethernet interface and it re-establishes the connection (I don't have a problem with my WiFi interface).

Answer (score 1):

Further to @agarza's comment I tried the following successfully.

In **System Preferences** > **Network**, I deleted the WiFi option in the left list (which for me had Thunderbolt Bridge & iPhone USB as alternative options)

I applied this.

I then clicked the '+' and added a new wifi option.

This instantly solved the issue.

Comment: You may not have to delete the interface completely but just make it inactive. Try the menu next to the "-" and select "Make service inactive".